# Compare 2 arrays with nested for loops

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays:

```
a = [{name:"test3", input:[{val:3}]}, {name:"ss", input:[{val:84}]},{name:"sss", input:[{val:86}]},{name:"test", input:[{val:6}]}, {name:"some", input:[{val:8}]}]

a2 = [{name: "dd", field:3},{name: "dd", field:6}]
```

Now I'm trying to get unique values from both the arrays using `

`filter`:

```
    a.forEach(function(i){
 i.input.forEach(function(j){
  a2.filter(function(k){return j.val !== k.field;});
});})
```

and then I want to use: `forEach(function(p){p.remove()}); //remove the unique values`

so I'm comaparing the `val` value from first array to the `field` value in the second one:

the expected outcome:

```
[{name:"ss", input:[{val:84}]},{name:"sss", input:[{val:86}]},{name:"some", input:[{val:8}]}]  // these are the ones whose `val` from `a` does not match with the `field` from `a2`
```

The above code returns nothing, any idea what could be missing?

Comment: `filter` does not modify the array on which it's called, therefore the line where you use it won't do anything because you're not capturing the filtered array.

Comment: It's not clear when you say you want "unique values from both" what you mean because the arrays have different kinds of objects. It would help if you added your desired outcome.

Comment: What is the last forEach supposed to do? What constitutes a unique value?

Comment: have updated to show the outcome

Comment: Well you have a syntax error in your code you posted, so did you copy in your code incorrectly, or are you getting an error when you run your code?

Comment: fixed the syntax, still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the first array based on finding if an element with that input val exists in the second array through a double filter:

```js
let a = [{name:"test3", input:[{val:3}]}, {name:"ss", input:[{val:84}]},{name:"sss", input:[{val:86}]},{name:"test", input:[{val:6}]}, {name:"some", input:[{val:8}]}]

let a2 = [{name: "dd", field:3},{name: "dd", field:6}]

let results = a.filter(e => {
    return a2.filter(q => q.field === e.input['val']).length < 1;
});

console.log(results)
```

Comment: sorry didnt realize I need to mention this, but for this this: ```e.input[0]```input[{val:3}], ```val``` may not always be at the first position its dynamic object and it may have other elements in it depending on some condition, I think ```e.input[0]`` would fail then..do we have another approach here?

Comment: Do you mean that there can be multiple objects in the array? Is there a reason input can't just be an object instead of an array of one property objects? Just not sure I understand the big picture here @user1234

Comment: yes, there could be multiple object iin the ```input``` array, just that ```val`` field will always be there and other fields are depending on some condition..

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a simpler approach:

1. Create a list of the values you will use to filter your data.
2. Filter your data with it.

```js
const a = [{name: "test3", input: [{val: 3 }] }, {name: "ss", input: [{val: 84 }] }, {name: "sss", input: [{val: 86 }] }, {name: "test", input: [{val: 6 }] }, {name: "some", input: [{val: 8 }] } ]; 
const a2 = [{name: "dd", field: 3 }, {name: "dd", field: 6 }];

const filterBy = a2.map(v => v.field); // [3, 6]
const res = a.filter(el => !el.input.some(input => filterBy.includes(input.val)))

console.log(res)
```